# Bootstrap Checkbox not working in nav-pills

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, nav-pills

I can't figure out why the second checkbox is not working. I'm sure it's something relating to Bootstrap / CSS, and this is not my forte.

The first checkbox works as expected, but something happens when I put the checkbox inside the nav-pills. Can someone help me out?

HTML:

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">Testcheckbox
  </label>
</div>

<ul id="menu" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li class="nav-divider"></li>
    <li>
        <a class="nav-menu-container" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#menu" href="#sub-menu">
            Sub-Menu
            <div class="sub-menu-caret-container"><span class="caret arrow"></span></div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked collapse in" id="sub-menu">
      <li data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sub-menu" href="#pv11">
        <div class="nav-sub-menu-container">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox">Testcheckbox
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sub-menu" href="#pv11"><a id="item1" class="nav-sub-menu-container" href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sub-menu" href="#pv11"><a id="item2" class="nav-sub-menu-container" href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      <li data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sub-menu" href="#item3"><a class="nav-sub-menu-container" href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li class="nav-divider"></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.sub-menu-caret-container {
  float: right;
}
.nav-menu-container {
  font-weight: bold;
}
ul.nav-stacked ul.nav-stacked > li > .nav-sub-menu-container {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

[Link to jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kieveli/fv5mrcrL/)

Comment: The problem is the `data-toggle` on the parent li. It shouldn't be there if clicking is for the checkbox.

Comment: Ahhhh Thank you!  You should make this an answer for magical vapor points!

Comment: I tested the code. and I agree with ZimSystem. He beat me to it.

Comment: @jmag "She" beat ya to it ;-)

Comment: As long as we're pronouning, I identify as an "attack helicopter".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data-toggle` on the parent `li` is overriding the checkbox click.

Comment: This makes the checkbox work, but the tab no longer works. Seems there might not be a way to have both?

Answer (score 3):

This is how i fixed my issue

```js
$('your-checkbox-selector').mouseover(function(){
     $(this).parents('a.nav-link ').removeAttr('data-toggle')
  }).mouseout(function(){
      $(this).parents('a.nav-link ').attr('data-toggle','pill')
  });
```